# android how to put hashset in an adapter to use in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, hashset

here's my problem, for example

i have a class that defines the object Receipt
this class has all the receipts in a HashSet

```
public static Set<Receipt> allInstances = new HashSet<Receipt>();
```

here i also have getNumber(), getDate(), etc all the getters

now in the android i want to display the receipts in a ListView
i already have the class 
    public class ReceiptListFragment extends ListFragment

here o the OnCreate method
what do i do?

i want max performance for my code
i already seen the listview and arrayadapter with ViewHolder to max performance codes in the web

my real problem is 
since i have an HashSet with objects i can't get in the adapter class in the getView method the getNumber to set the text in a textview
the only way i thought was doing like this

```
for(Receipt r : Receipt.allInstances){
TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.receipt_row);
tv.setText("" + r.getNumber());
```

adding dynamically

but doing this i'm not using an adapter what will happen to the performance?
also since i have an HashSet i don't have position
also it may have repeated objects (it's normal and intended)

should i do a loop like before and transfer all the hashset to a list just to use the listview and do setListAdapter
this doesn't look very good in terms of performance since the number of objects may be high

in terms of performance
it's better doing it dymically
or
passing all the objects to a list and use a adapter with viewholder etc like all the examples out there

or there is a better solution?

Comment: if you have a long listview and you care about performance, then you want to use an adapter (and utilize convert-view). you could iterate through your HashSet and put just the *strings* you want into coordinate arraylists and use those to work your adapter. that would be better in terms of performance than dealing with the object themselves. If you don't want anymore objects, you should put a `setPosition()` method in each receipt then only take action in the getview if the correct `getPosition()` object matches the hascode you want but i think the first solution is much more straight-foward

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list, you could try this:

```
ArrayList<Receipt> receiptsList = new ArrayList<Receipt>(allInstances);
```

Create your `adapter` with the `receiptsList` and use `setListAdapter(adapter)`.
Take a look here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments